# Macbook Retina 2012/2013 (SATA) To m.2

Tags: ssd, sata, apple, adapter

I recently bought an adapter which allowed me to install a Samsung SSD in my Early 2013 Macbook 15 Pro with SATA.

However, now I have a spare 512 GB Apple SSD with it‘s proprietary interface. I‘d like to install it to an Intel NUC with some kind of „Apple 2012 Sata Ssd“ to m.2 adapter cable.

I couldn‘t find one. But I‘m probably not the first who wants to do this. Do you know an adapter and can recommend me one?